# How do you deal with Reapers

Tags: brutal-legend

I'm on the second run in with Ophilia's army and I'm having a bit of trouble dealing with her [Reapers](http://brutallegend.wikia.com/wiki/Reaper).

In addition to killing me when I get with in 30 feet, they also seem to be just as effective against my other troops.

How do I manage that situation?

Comment: similar discussion http://www.gamespot.com/xbox360/action/brutallegend/show_msgs.php?topic_id=m-1-53678650&pid=943672

Comment: This question had me so confused while I wondered why tzenes would need SC2 help.

Comment: I would ask who Ophilia is, but then you could as well add a spoiler a tag.

Comment: @Bronze I looked up that link and it essentially told me to rush her before she had a chance to get them out.  That works for the first major engagement, but in the second one they are there to start.  I ended up using the Stonesmasher to handle them, but the whole thing left me with a bad taste in my mouth.

Comment: i never played that game seriously, so I just looked this up and posted it :) sorry if it didn't help

Comment: Kill them with the Deuce

Answer (score 1):

The [one strategy](http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/943672-brutal-legend/faqs/58069) I found for this level seems to focus on turtling, then getting to Stage Level 4 so that you can deploy a Rock Crusher.  In the meantime, focus on building your army (leaving room for the Rock Crusher) and capturing the Fan Geysers on your side of the bridge separating you from her base.

Double Teaming with the Rock Crusher will allow you to pretty much pulverize her entire army, but watch out for her powerful Tree Back, which should be a major focus for your forces when she deploys it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the Deuce. Either the regular missiles or the heat seekers should be able to take them down pretty quickly. The key is getting their attention so they start charging you, otherwise it's hard to concentrate fire on them if they're running around the battlefield.

Once they start heading your way, simply back up and keep firing, and if they get too close, the side-mounted subwoofers can stun them for a few seconds.

This works equally well against lone Reapers you encounter in free-roam mode.